# Disable autorun of clamav on debian distro

Tags: debian, services, autorun

I have debian install on a machine with only 1gb of memory and clamav, that I have installed to run sometimes virus scan, is always in memory because of autostart, and take about 30% of total ram...

How to disable autostart of clamd service and run only when I need it?

Answer (score 1):

## ClamAV packages

ClamAV antivirus is splitted in several debian packages named [`clamav`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/clamav), [`clamav-freshclam`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/clamav-freshclam) and [`clamav-daemon`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/clamav-daemon) as stated in debian (jessie) package webpage:

> [...] a flexible and scalable multi-threaded daemon in the clamav-daemon package, a command-line scanner in the clamav package, and a tool for automatic updating via the Internet in the clamav-freshclam package. The programs are based on libclamav, which can be used by other software.

## ClamAV daemon auto-start

Auto-start of `clamd` daemon is fired by `/etc/init.d/clamav-daemon` script from package `clamav-daemon`. This gives you two options to disable automatic startup of this daemon:

- Uninstall `clamav-daemon` package, still keeping `clamav` and `freshclam`
- Or [disable auto-start](https://wiki.debian.org/Daemon) of the daemon installed by `clamav-daemon`:

```bsh
    # disable auto-start
    update-rc.d clamav-daemon disable
    # one-shot startup of the daemon when you want
    service clamav-daemon start
```

### ClamAV daemon notes

Note that reading your needs, I guess you might never want to start `clamd` (clamav-daemon) which goal is mostly dedicated to mail-server connectivity and on-access file scanning. Anyway, both options above should address your issue. The first option will also save ~1MiB of disk space which is not significant.